# javascript split string on multiple fields using regex

Tags: javascript, string, split, dsl

I'm trying to build a handy dsl-ish query ability into my javascript.

given:

```
var query = "lastName = 'smith' and firstName = 'jack' or city = 'vancouver'";
```

what's the most elegant way of parsing this sql-esque string into usable objects such as:

```
[
{
 field:'lastName',
 operator:'=',
 value:'smith',
 join:'and'
},
{
 field:'firstName',
 operator:'=',
 value:'jack',
 join:'or'
},
{
 field:'city',
 operator:'=',
 value:'vancouver'
}
]
```

Before I start hopelessly looping I figured there would be some regex master that had a one-liner.

Comment: If you are querying from a database PLEASE DONT use a regex. loop and validate each element before send to the backend.

Comment: Do you have rules for precedence? (ie. and before or)

Answer (score 0):

Create a grammar (EBNF or BNF) and then write a parser for it. Not only will you have more hair left on your head (you're going to end up pulling your hair out if you try to do this with regular expressions!), you will learn something new and cool :).

If you write a recursive-descent parser, you can easily represent your query as a tree.

Here's an EBNF to get you started:

```
query            ::= criterion { criterion }
criterion        ::= boolean-operator { filter }
boolean-operator ::= "not" | "or" | "and"
filter           ::= variable, "=", value
```